# How to remove watcher in ng-aria

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I used in `ng-matiral` and `ng-aria`, I need  to remove watcher from `ng-aria` 
I wanted to know how I remove  the Watcher in `ng-aria` (material)

Comment: please post some code